# Changing variable in a loop

Tags: python, loops

i tried a lot of different things its either error or it adds literly just 1 of the value.
Im trying that after every loop iteration it changes from group_1 to group_2. If i solely put group_1 then it works but that is not the goal.

i would like to hear out your ideas.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()



species = ["Adelie", "Gentoo", "Chinstrap"]

group_1 = df[df['species'] == 'Adelie']['culmen_depth_mm']
group_2 = df[df['species'] == 'Chinstrap']['culmen_depth_mm']
group_3 = df[df['species'] == 'Gentoo']['culmen_depth_mm']

froup_1 = df[df['species'] == 'Adelie']['culmen_length_mm']
froup_2 = df[df['species'] == 'Chinstrap']['culmen_length_mm']
froup_3 = df[df['species'] == 'Gentoo']['culmen_length_mm']



### code
#for i, col in range(3):
for i, col in enumerate(species, 0):
    group = group_ + i
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = group , y = froup, mode ='markers', name = col ))
    
  
    
    


fig.update_layout()
fig.show()
```

Comment: Do you think that `group = group_ + i`, when `i` is `1`, is equivalent to `group = group_1`? That's not how that works at all.

Comment: @RandomDavis How do i do it then, i have no clue.

Comment: See the answer by @arlaine. Instead of referring to the groups by the variable name, you can just store the variables inside a list and loop through the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding the question correctly, but you could make a list with your groups inside, and just loop over this list instead of the species variable, like so :

```
species_names = ["Adelie", "Gentoo", "Chinstrap"]

group_1 = df[df['species'] == 'Adelie']['culmen_depth_mm']
group_2 = df[df['species'] == 'Chinstrap']['culmen_depth_mm']
group_3 = df[df['species'] == 'Gentoo']['culmen_depth_mm']

fgroup_1 = df[df['species'] == 'Adelie']['culmen_length_mm']
fgroup_2 = df[df['species'] == 'Chinstrap']['culmen_length_mm']
fgroup_3 = df[df['species'] == 'Gentoo']['culmen_length_mm']

species = [group_1, group_2, group_3]
fspecies = [fgroup1, fgroup_2, fgroup_3]

for i, group in enumerate(species):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=group, y=fspecies[i], mode='markers', name=species_names[i]))


fig.update_layout()
fig.show()
```

Comment: Small typo fgroup_1 but thanks for providing me the answer :D